# How to extract data from html tag with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I need to extract address information from this HTML code.

```
     <span>
        <span class="icon"> <i class="fas fa-building"></i> </span> 8  Phạm Hùng
         Cau Giay
         Ha Noi
     </span>
```

How can I get that information. If I do something like

`response.css('div.company-info__location').get()`

I got back

```
<div class="company-info__location">      <span>\n        <span class="icon"> <i class="fas fa-building"></i> </span> 8  Phạm Hùng\nCau Giay\nHa Noi\n 
     </span>\n    </div>
```

Or

```
response.css('div.company-info__location::text').get()
```

It only return space.
Not exactly what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `string()` XPath expression:

```
response.xpath('string(//div[@class="info__location"])').get()
```